# Migration from Android to iPhone

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

We developed an Android app using PhoneGap and Jquery Mobile, and we want it to be operational on iPhone.
I want to know how can I convert it and which tools should I use.

Answer (score 1):

Get a Mac, install XCode from the App Store and code away. If your Android app was mainly written in C/C++ you can run that code with very little changes on iOS. If you used Java however, you'll have to rewrite a lot of that in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Most people use PhoneGap because they want to be able to deploy their app to multiple operating systems without having to port it to the native languages, frameworks and idioms of each platform. If that's what you want to do, just use PhoneGap Build, which lets you upload your HTML, CSS and JavaScript and get back an app tailored for each platform.

The result is a sort of hybrid between a web application and a native application which keeps your maintenance costs across multiple platforms lower but is likely not going to be as native-feeling as writing a custom native application for each platform. There are [tradeoffs](https://www.google.ca/webhp?q=pros%20cons%20phonegap) in both directions to using PhoneGap this way.

The alternative would be to build a native application for iOS using Objective-C, iOS APIs and  Xcode. This would give you a native iOS app that can take full advantage of the iPhone platform, but would mean that you have to maintain two codebases. If you wanted to go down this path, I'm not entirely certain why you would have used PhoneGap rather than Java to build the Android application.

Comment: yes! i want it to be a native iPhone app!!

Comment: is there any tutorial to explain how to proceed via PhoneGap ?

Comment: I think the easiest way for you would be to use PhoneGap Build: https://build.phonegap.com/